# ListView jumping to top (ISupportIncrementalLoading)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps

I've got a `ListView` bound to an `ObservableCollection` that implements `ISupportIncrementalLoading`. Everything is working nicely however when new items are added to the collection via `LoadMoreItemsAsync()` the `ListView` jumps to the top of the list.

The `ListView` should of course carry on scrolling from the current position. Any ideas what could be wrong?

UPDATE:

There is no selected item and individual items are added one at a time i.e.: 10 items added results in 10 collection changed events. It shouldn't be the last item in the list after its been updated, but the first updated item.

Comment: same here, i'm wondering that no one else is having this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.ScrollIntoView(i);
```

where i is the i-th selected item.